# How to install talend in silent mode (unattended mode)?

Tags: linux, talend, silent-installer

I have talend installer in my directory and now i want to run talend in silent mode so it do not give me options while running it on command line

my command to execute talend in silent mode :-
./Talend-Installer-20151214_1327-V6.1.1-linux64-installer.run --optionfile silentMode.txt

As soon as i run the above command i get the version and build detail but I cannot find it in the directory that i have given in me key value text file i.e /opt/talend-6.1.1. below is the result i get after executing the command.

"Talend 6.1.1 --- Built on 2015-12-14 18:02:36 IB: 9.5.3-201412111637"
Can anyone help me installing talend in silent mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying what components of Talend you are installing in unattended mode. The option file is there for that. So, let's say you would like to install TAC using included H2 DB and a JobServer, your option file (silentMode.txt that you are specifying) would probably look similar to the following:

```
mode=unattended
enable-components=tac,jobserver,serv
disable-components=logserv,mdm,dsc,cmdline,soa,runtime,svn,tdqp,sap_rfc,studio,esb
prefix=/opt
installStyle=advanced
installType=custom
licenseFile=/talend_packages/license
tacAdminUser=admin@company.com
tacAdminPwd=admin
tacWebAppName=tac611
svnInstall=create
svnUser=svnadmin
svnPass=admin
```

Please notice, that you have to specify both enable-components and disable-components together. If you don't, it might try to install all components and result in an error (since it misses necessary information from the option file). Don't ask me why ...

In order to get an exhaustive list of options to put in your optionfile, simply take a look at the installer's options:

```
# ./Talend-Installer-20151214_1327-V6.1.1-linux64-installer.run --help
```

The same content is available [here](https://help.talend.com/download/attachments/265093581/Talend-6.1.1_unattended_installation_options.txt?version=1&modificationDate=1449220563000&api=v2)

Please also notice that it is recommended to install Talend using root (in order to activate RC scripts, etc.), but you can then, manually change Talend Directory owner to another user and slightly modify the RC scripts to run services as that user.

Some more documentation could be read [here](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=265102474)

Comment: I am trying to install Apache Tomcat, TAC, Command Line and Nexus  in my Talend.

Comment: I am trying to install Apache Tomcat, TAC, Command Line and Nexus  in my Talend.
I added the enable and disabled options in my silentMode.txt as you suggested

mode=unattended
unattendedmodeui=none
enable-components=tac,jobserver,cmdline
disable-components=logserv,mdm,dsc,soa,runtime,svn,tdqp,sap_rfc,studio,esb,serv
version=6.1.1
licenseFile=/tmp/license
prefix=/opt/talend-6.1.1
installType=full
installStyle=easy
tomcat=install8
tacAdminUser=admin@company.com
tacAdminPwd=admin
tacDB=postgresql
tacPort=8080
tacWebAppName=org.talend.administrator
tacSetupEmailNotification=false